# Is it ever possible to "win" a 50/50 game with a clear goal in mind.

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Lets say I have 750 dollars and want at least 1250 dollars at the end of a 50/50 game where I can bet any possible value. Is there any way in which I can raise my chances of winning? And if there is, how can I define the best initial bet to be doubled?

(At first I thought problems like these were easy to solve and there was no possible way to "win", but at the same time I have some doubts about it and don't know the mathematical explanation for it.)

Comment: Actually, this is quite complicated.  See https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/joma/Volume8/Siegrist/RedBlack.pdf

Comment: The proper search term is "How to gamble if you must"

Comment: At the time of writing there are two answers. Both are very convincing and also (in a sense) completely opposite. I love this question already!

Answer (score 4):

By "50/50 game" I assume you mean you can make any sequence of fair bets at $50/50$ odds, as long as you never bet more than you have at the time.
Since these are fair bets, your expected value at the end is the same as
your initial fortune, $750$.  As long as you ensure that the only possible final outcomes are
$0$ and $1250$, you maximize the probability of ending with $1250$.
Thus one possible strategy is: whenever you have $x$ where $0 < x < 1250$, bet the minimum of $x$ and $1250 - x$.  With probability $1$, you will eventually end up at either $1250$ or $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Your optimal probability of getting to \$1250 from \$750 with fair bets is **60%** and you cannot do better. One strategy of doing so is given by @Robert's answer above, called "[bold play](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/joma/Volume8/Siegrist/RedBlack.pdf)" in the literature. If you follow his strategy, you find yourself along the following tree:

[image: A tree diagram that shows the potential outcomes of bold play. Starting with a bet of 750, winning outcomes either go 750 to 1250; 750 to 250 to 500 to 1000 to 1250; or 750 to 250 to 500 to 1000 and then back to 750, starting over.]

You take each path of this betting tree with probability $1/2$. If your initial probability of winning from \$750 is x, then one of three things happen on your way to victory:

1. You win instantly ($50\%$ chance)
2. After an initial loss, you win 3x in a row ($1/16 = 6.25\%$ chance)
3. After an initial loss and 2 wins, you lose again and get back to your starting fortune of \$750 ($1/16 = 6.25\%$ chance)

So we have the equation $$x = 0.5 + 0.0625 + 0.0625x,$$ and when solved, we learn that $x = 9/16 + x/16$, or $15x/16 = 9/16$, whence $x = 9/15 = 0.6$. (The other $40\%$ probability is that you go broke.)

*Why can't we do better than $60\%$?* Consider your fortune $W_n$ on the $n$th bet, and imagine you make the bet $A_n$ subject to the constraints $A_n = 0$ if $W_n \geq 1250$ or $W_n = 0$, $0 \leq A_n \leq W_n$. Then $W_n$ is a [uniformly integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability) [martingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(probability_theory)), because your winning probability on each bet is $1/2$ and $$0 \leq W_n \leq 2*(1250-1) = 2498$$ is a bounded sequence above and below. This means that $W_n$ [converges almost surely and in $L^1$ to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems#Doob%27s_second_martingale_convergence_theorem) a bounded random variable $W_\infty$, representing your limiting winnings. The $L^1$ convergence is crucial here, as it means $$\Bbb{E}[W_\infty] = 750.$$

You have "won" your betting sequence if $W_\infty \geq 1250$. What is the probability of that? By [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality), $$\Bbb{P}(W_\infty \geq 1250) \leq \frac{\Bbb{E}[W_\infty]}{1250} \leq \frac{750}{1250} = 60\%.$$

(If you started with $x$ dollars instead, the same argument shows you have an $x/1250$ chance of getting to \$1250, one way to do this being bold play.)

So bold play actually gives you the "best possible" chance of reaching \$1250--although it's also "worst possible" among strategies that achieve $60\%$, as the other $40\%$ of your time you lose all of your initial \$750.

Other betting strategies than bold play may leave you with a better probability of a nonzero limiting fortune $W_\infty$ (one example: bet $1/(n+1)$ of your current wealth $W_n$ on bet number $n$ or $1250 - W_n$, whichever is smaller). But no strategy, however clever or intricate, can do better than a $60\%$ chance of reaching \$1250 from an initial stake of \$750.

Comment: If we goes lower the wished amount, for example $850, then exists other strategy with more chance of winning?

Comment: If you want to get from \$750 to \$850 then your highest chance of winning is $750/850 = 15/17 = 88.2\%$. Bold play achieves this: a strategy that maximizes your chance of reaching \$850 is to bet the lesser of $2x$ and $850-x$. Argument is the same as above.